# Android Gradle Multidex Build issue on API 19

Tags: android, android-multidex

I have a project in which I have enabled `multidex` to avoid `65k limit` and also `productFlavors` (dev API 21 and prod API 19) for customization.
Building my Project on `API 21` i.e dev flavor is successful but on `API 19` i.e. prod flavor, it is continuously giving me exception in app task `shrink{component}MultiDexComponents`

Complete Error log:

```
:app:shrinkProdDebugMultiDexComponents FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:shrinkProdDebugMultiDexComponents'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't read [{Project Path}/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/prod/debug/allclasses.jar] (Can't process class [com/olivephone/office/a/b/e/p.class] (Unknown verification type [17] in stack map frame))
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {  
    compileSdkVersion 23  
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'  
    defaultConfig {  
        applicationId '{Project Name}'  
        minSdkVersion 15  
        targetSdkVersion 23  
        versionCode 1  
        versionName "1.0"  
        multiDexEnabled true  
    }  
    productFlavors {  
        dev {  
            // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin  
            // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on  
            // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.  
            minSdkVersion 21  
        }  
        prod {  
            // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.  
            minSdkVersion 19  
        }  
    }  
    buildTypes {  
        release {  
            minifyEnabled false  
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'  
        }  
    }  
}  

dependencies {  
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')  
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'  
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'  
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'  
    compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'  
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'  
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'  
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'  
    compile files('libs/linkedin-j-android.jar')  
    compile files('libs/itsrts-pptviewer.jar')  
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')  
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'  
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2-SNAPSHOT-with-sources.jar')
    compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar')  
    compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')  
    compile 'com.joanzapata.pdfview:android-pdfview:1.0.1@jar'  
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'  
}
```

Any help please anyone ??

Comment: Already did !! No luck there

Comment: Are you using Proguard?

Comment: @Fondesa No not using Proguard

Comment: @AndiGeeky Edited Question with build.gradle

Comment: the problem is with compile files('libs/itsrts-pptviewer.jar')  this one. the jar file inside the libs folder. if you remove it then it will work

Comment: Did you get it to work? If yes, how? I'm stuck..

Answer (score 11):

**Multidex support for Android 5.0 and higher**

> Android 5.0 and higher uses a runtime called ART which natively
>   supports loading multiple dex files from application APK files. ART
>   performs pre-compilation at application install time which scans for
>   classes(..N).dex files and compiles them into a single .oat file for
>   execution by the Android device. For more information on the Android
>   5.0 runtime, see Introducing ART.

This is the reason why your app is working fine on API level 21.

**Multidex support prior to Android 5.0**

> Versions of the platform prior to Android 5.0 use the Dalvik runtime
>   for executing app code. By default, Dalvik limits apps to a single
>   classes.dex bytecode file per APK. In order to get around this
>   limitation, you can use the multidex support library, which becomes
>   part of the primary DEX file of your app and then manages access to
>   the additional DEX files and the code they contain.

So, Firstly making sure you have imported correct dependency, which It seems you did it.

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

In your manifest add the `MultiDexApplication` class from the multidex support library to the application element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Alternative to that, If your app extends the `Application` class, you can override the `attachBaseContext()` method and call `MultiDex.install(this)` to enable `multidex`.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
    MultiDex.install(getTargetContext());
    super.onCreate(arguments);
    ...
}
```

I hope it will help you out.

Comment: Thanks.. Bhuvesh I just add below code in my application file it do the trick ,no BUNDLE in oncreate no attachBaseContext() in that and before that i was only using MULTIDEX JAR in my build but my app was crashing below api 21  at run time.. now its working do not know reason behind that.
public void onCreate( ) {
  MultiDex.install(this);
  super.onCreate();

  // initialize the singleton
  sInstance = this;
 }

Answer (score 1):

In API 21, `:app:shrinkProdDebugMultiDexComponents` command is not called as API 21 already uses ART instead of Dalvik. Thus, natively support multidex.

For API below 21, then the command `:app:shrinkProdDebugMultiDexComponents` is executed.
Checking your `build.gradle` everything looks fine, which brings me to the following.

Have you setup multidex support properly?

Have you setup your manifest to support Multidex?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
  <application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

OR if you actually extending the application class, you can do this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
       super.attachBaseContext(base);
       MultiDex.install(this);
    }
    ...     
}
```

or use this "pre-built" version

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication{

 ...     

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't peeped into the logic behind this, but in my case, it was due to version conflicts of `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` and `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'` in my *build.gradle* file.

Only enabling `multidex` didn't work for me. While searching for the other solutions, I found some people complaining about wierd issue of version conflict of `play-services`. So, I backtracked the code changes and finally changed `play-services` version from **10.2.4** to **10.2.1** and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Solved above crash issue. I have remove some unused dependency and also removed rx java dependency `io.reactivex.rxjava` . In replacement of Rx java i have added some dummy classes in my package which is already described here https://realm.io/docs/java/latest.

```
// File 1
package io.reactivex;
public class Flowable {
}
// File 2
package io.reactivex;
public class Observable {
}
// File 3
package io.reactivex;
public enum BackpressureStrategy {
   LATEST;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your dependencies as below :

Edited dependencies:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.googlecode.linkedin-j:linkedin-j-core:1.0.416'
compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'
compile files('libs/itsrts-pptviewer.jar')
compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar')
compile 'com.joanzapata.pdfview:android-pdfview:1.0.1@jar'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
```

Reason is that 'compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])' includes all jar file to gradle that is in libs folder..

Thanks.!!

Answer (score 0):

The shrinkProdDebugMultiDexComponents task [invokes Proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27207969/1233652), so this error comes from Proguard [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/proguard/+/master/src/proguard/classfile/io/ProgramClassReader.java#1055).

My guess will be that you're not using the latest version of Olive Office SDK (which is probably obfuscated with buggy or misconfigured Proguard version). If this is the case, get the latest version from SDK developer.

For workaround, check [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/420/) similar bug. Although it was closed with wontfix status, [this blogpost](http://innodroid.com/blog/post/use-a-custom-proguard-build-with-gradle/) describes how to patch the Proguard code.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8882790/1233652) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24855677/1233652) answers by Eric Lafortune (Proguard's author) on similar issues.